# Querying Hours in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I was wondering if it's possible to do in hibernate criteria querying a table specifying hours. For example I have mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM eventlog WHERE HOUR(CREATED_AT) BETWEEN 8 AND 16 
         AND CREATED_AT BETWEEN '2013-01-01 11:00:00' AND '2013-01-08 11:00:00'
```

which I want to convert in criteria:

```
criteria.add(Property.forName("HOUR(created_at)").between(8, 16));
criteria.add(Property.forName("created_at").between('2013-01-01 11:00:00', '2013-01-08 11:00:00'));
```

It must be pretty simple but I am really stacked on this.

I would appreciate any help. Thx

Comment: Ok, I have changed it to hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found one possible solution. Although there must be another way to do it I'll put it here for your information.

```
String sql = "HOUR(CREATED_AT) BETWEEN 8 AND 16";
criteria.add(Expression.sql(sql));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate-between-date.shtml), they do something similar to your question.